# How to host a rails web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hosting, web-hosting

I have developed a nifty web application using rails and would like to host it. Unfortunately I'm unsure how i can cheaply host my application. I'm aware of various deployment tools like capistrano and I've also herd of Heroku. I presume these tools help in hosting.

However can anyone provide me the steps to host a web app in details esp using rails and what all options i can have for doing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*EDIT*

It has been pointed out to me that a link in my answer does no longer work. Which is not that surprising, since this is a 3 year old answer.
Because It seems like people are still stumbling on this answer, I would like to redirect people to this page:

https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04

It should have all the information you need to deploy a rails application.

*End EDIT*

I recommend that you check out

http://rubyonrails.org/deploy

to start with.

And also 
http://www.cloudfoundry.com/
and 
https://www.engineyard.com/

are both great hosts for any rails application, and they also have some pretty easy to follow step-by-step tutorials on how to do so.

As Leito mentioned Heroku in his answer, I would like to point you to 
http://www.codeschool.com/code_tv/heroku

If you choose Heroku as your host, you could check out that video as it shows you how to deploy a simple rails application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I consider myself an advance user, but it's always good to go to the basics, and have a fresh reminder!

Comment: ror.org/deploy link is dead now.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out to me @YoTengoUnLCD . I have edited the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check the date! Thanks for providing a new link.

Answer (score 2):

Heroku is the easiest in my opinion, I recommend you start here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3

Heroku is more an application hosting and uses git to deploy your app, so no need of capistrano or similar tools.

Comment: Thanks a ton Leito. I can actually host my app too using the above method right?

Comment: Capistrano will allow you to setup a machine from scratch, usually a VM hosted in services like EC2 or Rackspace. It's way more complicated and I recommend you start with Heroku first, and gradually move out to the platform of your choice once you have more experience.