# How To Convert Rails Application Into An Actual Site

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, github

I built a simple todo list application on Rails. I built it through Team Treehouse. It was one of the courses. I am wondering how would I convert it to a site. The reason being is because it would be a nice to add to my portfolio (I have yet to style it though). Would I simply upload the application to my github then go through such as I would to create a website through Github pages?

[image]

I plan to buy a url for it. I am just simply trying to gauge out how would I approach converting it into a site. My apologies, it is a noob question.

Comment: You can try to deploy your app into [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)

Comment: You no need to buy any url, you can use heroku which is free upto 5 apps.

Comment: Github pages is for static HTML content - you need a web server or SASS provider that can run ruby and a database. Heroku is one such provider but there are many more. Also you don't buy URL's - a url is just an address - you buy domain names and the infrastructure to serve the site that lives behind it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373856/how-to-host-a-rails-web-application

Answer (score 0):

you can push your code to github and sign in to a heroku account and push it there. There are lot of documentation on how to  do that based on your rails application versions. [how to put a rails application on heroku](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GV40aaY2m3g) or [getting started with rails4 and heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4)

Answer (score 0):

Create a heroku account. You can rename the domain grocerylist.heroku.com for example. No need to buy a domain.